# Genizah and electronic file

Tags: halacha, modern-times, holy-objects, genizah-storage, contemporary-halacha

Has the subject of genizah been treated about electronic content?

For example, if it is permitted to delete (and even *cut*-and-paste) a computer file containing divrei Torah. Or to delete a .jpg picture file known to show in its background an open sefer Torah.

All pointers welcome. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry for the dup. Before asking, I checked questions tagged genizah-storage. Other one tagged sheimot ...

Comment: Even if, this question about divrei tora, while the other one is about Names.

Comment: Anyway, @ the kind closer: good idea to leave a comment before closing a question, no? Maybe the asker could explain, or delete his question.